# Apache Beam - sliding windows for kinesis stream

Tags: apache-beam, sliding-window

I am trying to do a sliding window of 1 hr(3600 secs TimeWindowSize) and 5 secs(TimeWindowSamplingFrequency) with kinesis stream processed events,
but I am receiving the processed events in every 5 secs and its not doing the sliding window of 1 hr to give me the one hour result of the events transform i want.

As per my understand , it should wait and process the 1 hour events coming in from kinesis stream and then give me an output after 1 hr.

*following is the sample code i used*

```
 pipeline.apply(
  KinesisIO.read()
    .withStreamName(options.getEnrichedSnowplowEventsStreamName())
    .withAWSClientsProvider(new DefaultAWSClientsProvider())
    .withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.LATEST))
  .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
    .via(record -> new String(record.getDataAsBytes())))
  .apply(ParseSnowplowEvents.fromStrings())

  .apply(a userdefined ParDo transform which gives an op of 
  PCollection<Class> objects )

  .apply(Window
    .into(SlidingWindows
      .of(
        Duration.standardSeconds(
          3600))
      .every(Duration.standardSeconds(
        5))
    )).apply(
  a userdefined transform with ParDo which gives me the o/p of PCollection<KV<Integer, Double>>>)
 .apply(PrintValue.andPassOn());
```

PrintValue.andPassOn() userdefined transform prints the data for me , but i am expecting the result PCollection<KV<Integer,Double>> at the end of one hour sliding window , instead it prints out at every 5 secs the KV pairs

---

> 2018-06-17T13:11:29.999Z - KV{101, 5.0}
> 2018-06-17T13:11:34.999Z - KV{102, 0.4}
> 2018-06-17T13:11:39.999Z
>
> - KV{104, 0.5}

---

Answer (score 0):

It is printing as per your sampling frequency. Change it to one hour and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So Even if the frequency is 5 secs, since the window is 1 hr , will it do the transformation on 1 hour worth data and give me the result ?